# UIBarButtonItem moves inward after altering it programmatically

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uibarbuttonitem

I added some UIBarButtonItems to a navigationBar in interface builder. Then I change the buttons (remove,change title or add removed buttons) programatically, and the button indents something like 15 pixels inwards (away from the left/right border of the navigationbar). After the view is reloaded the buttons are back in their original place.

An example is the edit button at the top of a table view: it moves a little bit inward after i change it from edit to done. When I switch it from done back to edit, it stays in the same awkward position.

Can anyone tell me how this comes, and especially what I should do to prevent it?

Comment: Please add the code so that we can see the issue.

Comment: I was gonna past the code, but pasting the code made me realise some possible solutions. It turns out that I was changing the title of the UIBarButtonsItems in some cases instead of making to buttons and showing the appropriate one. That left me with the situation where after popping a pushed viewcontroller the leftbarbuttonitem in the parent-viewcontroller was indented 15px to the right. I solved this by calling setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(-15, 0) on the button if a viewcontroller is popped. It seems to me like a dirty hack but I haven't been able to figure out what caused it.